# How do you filter a layer on a joined table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, sql-server-spatial

I am attempting to do a join in QGIS between a SQL Server Spatial table and a non-spatial table (on a single integer field).  I was able to add both successfully and make the join, but the query builder dialog only shows the fields from the spatial table.

I also tried setting a feature filter on the non-spatial table before joining to the spatial table, but that filter was not honored (no error, but no affect on the layer).

`QGIS version: 2.12.1-Lyon    QGIS code revision: 16760fd`

`Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
    Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)`

Comment: would loading the non-spatial table into MSSQL be out of the question / workflow?

Comment: The non-spatial table IS an MSSQL table.  For environments where I can, I just build a spatial view that does the filtering that I need.  But for other environments and/or users w/ limited privs, can the filtering be done with the software?

Comment: Try saving your joined layer as a shapefile in order to save all columns in a proper file? Joining tables in QGIS is a temporary  process that often need saving into a new file to be able to work with all columns, including the joined ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these 2 feature requests which seem to confirm that you can't filter the layer on the joined table.  The workaround is to export the layer to shapefile as [@wiltomap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/22693/wiltomap) suggested (provided the data is static).

[Not possible to define subset of layer using field from joined table](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/3858)

[query / filter on attribute tables with external tables joined](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/8141)