# Filter on joined tables in QGIS

Tags: qgis, excel, table, filter

QGIS 3.2.3: I have a shapefile and an Excel table which is joined to the shapefile based on matching IDs.

I would like to **filter the shapefile while using a joined field from the Excel table.**

When I select "Filter" at the shapefile, I get the message that filter on joined tables is only possible when creating a "Virtual Layer". I click "Yes" when asked if I want to create a virtual layer.

Nevertheless, when the query builder appears, the joined fields do not appear. Did the creation of the "virtual layer" not work?

Is this not possible or am I doing something wrong?

I have found this older article: is this still valid that it is not possible in QGIS? [How do you filter a layer on a joined table in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174608/how-do-you-filter-a-layer-on-a-joined-table-in-qgis)

This works in ArcGIS using a "definition query" on a joined layer.

Comment: any feedback? how do you deal with this issue?

Comment: Not a full answer but this might help: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html

Comment: Thank you. This describes to process of the join which is working. It does not give information about the issue of filtering when using a joined field in the query.

Comment: Try to use `"Save as..."` a new shapefile your extended shapefile (a shapefile with joint Excel table).

Comment: Thank you Taras, but exporting to a new file is not a workaround since the new data would be static (and not dynamic).

Comment: Have you defined your joins both in Settings → Project Properties → Relations and in Layer → Properties → Joins?  Make sure you've added all the foreign (i.e. excel) columns you want to use in both places. You might also need to set the Prefix in the latter if you have any field name collisions.  (Yes, QGIS joins are a PITA)  Since you're working with dynamic data also make sure Memory cache is disabled in the latter.

Comment: Thank you Alex. No I didn't have it defined in the project settings (relations), just in the layer properties. I've tried now to also add the excel table in the project settings (using parent and child with the same matching IDs as the join) but still, when filtering I only see the fields from the shapefile, and not from the excel. Does the filtering work for you or was this just an idea from you? Am I doing something wrong in the project settings?

Comment: Yes, the joined fields show up for me in the filter dialog.  Note that I'm using Postgres as my backend not shapefile+excel.   What I did encounter was the geometry column of the filtered table not displaying on the map.  Yes, joins are a pain in QGIS.  If you find a solution that works could you write an answer to your own question; I'm sure a lot of people would find it helpful.